# PhoneGap: Remote Logging with gwt-log

Tags: java, android, ios, gwt, cordova

I use [gwt-phonegap](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/) with [gwt-log](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) in a iOs PhoneGap environment.

I use gwt-log with remote logging which works fine. My app is also running in a PhoneGap container.

My web.xml configuration is the following:

```
<module rename-to='mobilePhoneGapIOS'>

<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-TRACE" />
<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-RemoteLogger" />

<set-property name="log_DivLogger" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="log_FirebugLogger" value="DISABLED" />


<set-property name="compiler.emulatedStack" value="true" />
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>

   ...
```

My web.xml contains:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GWT-Log-remote-logger-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.mobilePhoneGapIOS.server.MyRemoteLoggerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>symbolMaps</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/deploy/mobilePhoneGapIO/symbolMaps</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GWT-Log-remote-logger-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mobilePhoneGapIOS/gwt-log</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried to log the following exception:

```
Log.fatal("This is what an exception might look like", new RuntimeException("2 + 2 = 5"));
```

It works when I use it on my desktop browser but on phonegap it does not work. The output is:

```
2014-04-03 19:20:41.202 Test[29194:907] ERROR: (-:-) 2014-04-03 19:20:41,193 [FATAL] This is what an exception might look like
java.lang.RuntimeException: 2 + 2 = 5
    at Unknown._Jb(StackTraceCreator.java:180)
    at Unknown.ixb(StackTraceCreator.java:518)
    at Unknown.gxb(Throwable.java:56)
    at Unknown.Bzb(Exception.java:29)
    at Unknown.Ezb(RuntimeException.java:29)
    at Unknown.Cc(Mobile.java:81)
    at Unknown.Fc(Mobile.java:32)
    at Unknown.FJb(SchedulerImpl.java:180)
    at Unknown.wJb(SchedulerImpl.java:345)
    at Unknown.JJb(SchedulerImpl.java:78)
    at Unknown.DJb(SchedulerImpl.java:138)
    at Unknown.TIb(Impl.java:290)
    at Unknown.XIb(Impl.java:347)
    at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:93)
    at Unknown.anonymous(UnloadSupport.java:42)
```

**What do I have to change to make remote logging with stacktrace deobfuscation working in a Phonegap container?**

Comment: your comment does not help. I use gwt-log

Comment: Just as curiosity, why do you use gwt-log instead of core gwt logger handlers?

Comment: Gwt-log is much more easy to use

Comment: Your opinion :-). IMO gwt-log has more features (use it in server side, native android, better popups...). But just for more common cases (logging gwt to remote servers) you have to write the same code and almost the same configuration, but additionally you have to import the library.

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino I could not get gwt remote logging to make it work could you please post some code to explain how to make gwt remote logging working with Stacktrace deobfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never have used gwt-log since the official [logging mechanism in GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html) has always worked fine to me. So this is how I normally enable remote logging in my projects:

First you have to enable logging and remote handler in your module.gwt.xml file:

```
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

Second, your web.xml should have configured the url-pattern of remote logging like this (note that you have to set the exact pattern in your application).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
    <!-- replace gwt_test with your module name -->
    <url-pattern>/gwt_test/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Finally, use java loggers as usual:

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLoggerName");
 logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Something was wrong ", new RuntimeException("My error"));
```

If you want your exceptions being unobfuscated in server side, you have to implement your own servlet to activate it:

```
public class RemoteLoggingDeobfuscatorServlet extends RemoteLoggingServiceImpl {
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    // replace gwt_test with your module name
    String symbols = getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/deploy/gwt_test/symbolMaps/");
    super.setSymbolMapsDirectory(symbols);
  }
}
```

and change your web.xml

```
<servlet-class>your_namespace.RemoteLoggingDeobfuscatorServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: is it also possible to use GWT.log() instead.

Comment: No, from the javadoc: `GWT.log() logs a message to the development shell logger in Development Mode, or to the console in Super Dev Mode. Calls are optimized out in Production Mode`. This means that `GWT.log` is removed by default in production.

Comment: do I have to set GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler? If so can you explain how I have to set it that it works with remote logging?

Comment: Normally you have to set the exception handler at the beginning of your app, and in the body of the handler use java logger as usual. GWT compiler will take care of those logs depending on how you configure it for sending them to console, server, etc.